# True if "pure" string without formatting is in another "pure" string in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, string

I will cut straight to my issue.

I'm looking for a function that receives two strings, and if `string_2` contains `string_1` in it's pure form (without formatting, breaking and so on), than it will return true.

For example, let's call it `string_1` (note that this is repl of the actual string)

> "I understand that money is important in politics but, imagine if we had a party that was driven by the people and it put people's needs at its centre.\n\nI mean, why not dream big?"

is indeed contained in this repl (let's call it `string_2`)

> "Unathi Kwaza: I understand that money is important in politics but, imagine if we had a party that was driven by the people and it put people's needs at its centre. I mean, why not dream big?"

but due to formatting in `string_1`, the boolean `if string_1 is in string_2` won't work (will return `False`).

I tried to break down the two strings into lists of words and comparing if every item in the list of `string_1` is in `string_2` and it actually returns `True`, But I am sure that there's a much simpler, less resource-heavy approach to solve this simple problem.

Thanks in advance! Every help is appreciated.

Comment: So you basically want to ignore whitespace? You could remove all whitespace in both strings and then do the check (although that could create false positives: "a b c" would be equivalent to "abc")? Alternatively, normalize the whitespace (something like `" ".join(word for word in string.split() if word)`) and use the result for comparing

Comment: Thank you! Worked great